# How can I tell Visual Studio to not populate a field in the designer code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a custom control that when I drag onto the form, creates the following designer.cs code:

```
// 
// colorPickerBackground
// 
this.colorPickerBackground.Color = Color.Empty;
this.colorPickerBackground.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(256, 175);
this.colorPickerBackground.Name = "colorPickerBackground";
this.colorPickerBackground.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(156, 21);
this.colorPickerBackground.TabIndex = 17;
this.colorPickerBackground.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(this.colorPicke
```

I'd like it (Visual Studio) to completely ignore the .Color attribute and leave it be. How can I tell it to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Designer code says at the top "Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if the code is regenerated."  I take this to be pretty much self explanitory

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Please read the question, then read it again and again. Once more for the thrills, then attempt to answer.

Comment: @Sergio - well I am trying, but "I can a control that when I drag onto the form, " isn't exactly well formed english...pita

Comment: @Sergio: what do you mean you want it to "leave it alone"? What do you want the Color property set to? The default is `Color.Empty`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive a new class from the ColorPickerBackground class.  Override (or new) the Color property and decorate with the attributes found in System.ComponentModel...

Take a look at these:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public Color Color { get; set; }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx

Comment: BTW, These are the attributes used by MS when they hide properties exposed by Control in their derived classes.