# Can I stop Visual Studio auto-changing the form designer code?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm using visual studio and have some numericUpDown controls that I have set values for (min, max, value and increment).  The Code Designer keeps turning my simple decimal values into int[]. I know that it says "do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor" but I find it really useful to adjust properties in here and I thought I was just "making things neat" when I changed:

```
        this.numericUpDown1.Increment = new decimal(new int[] {
        2,
        0,
        0,
        0});
```

to

```
        this.numericUpDown1.Increment = new decimal(2);
```

but alas, it changes it back if I touch the control on the visual form designer.  I thought maybe there was a flag that would leave it as is until I want it to be updated.  It is more for readability and navigation but even if it would just leave it on one line I'd be happier.

I've found this ([How can I tell Visual Studio to not populate a field in the designer code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4663460/1024885)) where someone was trying to leave it but I'm not sure if it is applicable in this instance.

Feel free to tell me that I should just get over it and leave it alone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realised (thanks @Jonathan) that I could just create a separate section in the designer ABOVE that place ... this means I can have all my default values in a separate section as long as I don't want to changed the defaults on the form designer.  This is the method above InitializeComponent()

```
private void IntializeOtherComponents()
    {
      this.numericUpDown1.Value = new decimal(17);     
      this.numericUpDown1.Maximum = new decimal(7777);
      this.numericUpDown1.Minimum = new decimal(5); 
    }
```

Comment: Then why put it in the .Designer.cs at all? Why not just put it in your .cs, before or after you call InitializeComponent()? (Edit: this is different from Jonathan's answer.)

Comment: You are completely correct ...For readability, it may be the best way for me to be able to see and change things without even needing the designer.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own NumericUpDown user control. Just inherit from the common NumeriUpDown and set the dessired properties in the constructor.

```
public partial class MyUpDownCtrl : NumericUpDown
    {
        public MyUpDownCtrl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Increment = new decimal(2);

        }
    }
```

After generating your solution you will have your new custom UpDownControl in your Tool Box ready to use just dragging it like the common numericUpDown.

I hope it help you, because I don't know any way to make Visual Studio stop  auto-changing the form designer code. Maybe it can't be done at all.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me the idea I just posted in a self-answer.